# Наборы множеств символов

Tags: python

Имеется некоторая переменная

```
text = "Intel Core i9"
```

Необходимо составить различные варианты символов:

Код:

```
text = "Intel Core i9"

url = []
for i in range(len(text) + 1):
    for index in range(0, i):
        url.append(text[index:i])
url = sorted(url, reverse = True, key = len)
```

Можно ли как нибудь сделать более изящное решение, и чтобы результат сразу сортировался по длине, не пренебрегая к сортировки списка после прохождения данного алгоритма

**Для чего это нужно**:
У меня есть база данных с названиями продукта, я спарсил какие-то параметры таких же продуктов, и мне нужно сопоставить объекты по названию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
text = "Intel Core i9"

url=(sorted([text[i:j+1] for i in range(len(text)) for j in range(i,len(text))], reverse=True, key=len))
```

Либо, без дубликатов:

```
url=(sorted({text[i:j+1] for i in range(len(text)) for j in range(i,len(text))}, reverse=True, key=len))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
text = "Intel Core i9"

url = [

    text[first:first+length]
    for length in range(len(text), 0, -1)
    for first in range(len(text) - length + 1)
]
```

Comment: у вас не сортируется по длине

Comment: Поправил, теперь сортируется